# Beautifulsoup print value in div

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

Im trying to print the text after the value= field so far the output looks like this.

```
<div class="controls"><input class="span12 text-bound" id="client_appbundle_prospecttype_name" maxlength="100" name="client_appbundle_prospecttype[name]" required="required" type="text" value="John Smith"/></div>
```

My code looks like this.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

contact = soup.find('div', {"class": "controls"})

print(contact)
```

How can I print the text following the "value=" so just John Smith

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is faster to use an id when using CSS selectors and should be your first choice when available (And truly unique on page). You can then use `.get` to access the value of the `value` attribute of the matched element.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '<div class="controls"><input class="span12 text-bound" id="client_appbundle_prospecttype_name" maxlength="100" name="client_appbundle_prospecttype[name]" required="required" type="text" value="John Smith"/></div>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
print(soup.select_one('#client_appbundle_prospecttype_name').get('value'))
```